# Existe alguma forma de desabilitar a interface web do Scrapyd?

Tags: python, scrapy

Existe alguma forma de desabilitar a interface web do Scrapyd?

Gostaria de ficar monitorando o servidor somente pela api.

Comment: Fiquei curioso sobre o caso de uso, qual a desvantagem de ter a interface web?

Comment: Acontece que a partir do crawling de algumas milhares de páginas fica impraticável abrir a interface web. O servidor chegar a carregar e renderizar jsons bem pesados.

Answer (score 3):

O scrapyd não oferece essa opção.

Mas você consegue obter isso rodando uma instalação customizada com o código comentando essa linha: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/website.py#L24